# functional construct for flattening array for multiple row insert sql query

Tags: ios, sql, arrays, swift

Is there a way to generate multiple row sql query (values only) using some functional constructs of array?

I've an array of Roles that I want to insert into sqlite database.

```
struct Role {
    var id: Int32
    var name: String?
}

func updateByUserId(_ id: Int32, _ roles: [Role]) {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES( \(id), \(roles.map..) )"
}
```

**Expectation:**

for instances if `id` is `1` and `roles` has an array `[10, 11, 14, 15]`

Generated SQL should be

```
INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES(1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 14), (1, 15)
```

**SQL Syntax for Multiple row insert is**

> INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES(Value1, Value2),
> (Value1, Value2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` each role to the string `(id, role)`, then `join` the array of strings with the separator `,`:

```
let values = roles.map { "(\(id), \($0))" }.joined(separator: ", ")
let sql = "INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES\(values)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although for this particular scenario the SQL string computation is not problematic, it's good practice to use parametrized statements for every DB query.

Working exclusively with parametrized statements avoids vulnerabilities like SQL injection, or malformed queries that fail to execute (when dealing with strings instead of ints).

So, I'd recommend going via the above route by writing something like this:

```swift
func updateByUserId(_ id: Int32, _ roles: [Role]) -> (statement: String, params: [Int32]) {
    let statement = "INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES " + Array(repeating: "(?, ?)", count: roles.count).joined(separator: ", ")
    let params = roles.flatMap { [id, $0.id] }
    return (statement, params)
}
```

For your example in the question, the output would be something like this:

```
(statement: "INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)", params: [1, 10, 1, 11, 1, 14, 1, 15])
```

You can then use the SQLite functions to create the parametrized statement and bind the given values to it.

---

P.S. There is also the matter of validating that the array of roles is not empty, in which case you'd get an invalid SQL as output. To handle this, you can make the function return an optional, and nil will signal an empty array. Doing this will enable a small performance improvement, as you'll be able to use `String(repeating:count:)`, which is a little bit faster than creating an array and joing it later on:

```swift
func updateByUserId(_ id: Int32, _ roles: [Role]) -> (statement: String, params: [Int32])? {
    guard !roles.isEmpty else { return nil }
    return (statement: "INSERT INTO user_role(user_id, role_id) VALUES (?, ?)" + String(repeating: ", (?, ?)", count: roles.count - 1),
            params: roles.flatMap { [id, $0.id] })
}
```